# GreenDAO really simple query

Tags: greendao

I want to create a very simple query to look up a sqlite db using greendao. 2 fields, one is the ID and the other 'affirmation'.
i am sorry to be such a beginner, but i am not sure how to use greendao including what to import etc.. All i have been able to do so far is add  the greendao libraries but i cant find a good tutorial to just do a query. Basically i want it to be a random ID that calls up a random affirmation and return it to my main activity.. Once again i am sorry but i am really trying and getting nowhere..

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on how to use GreenDAO: http://blog.surecase.eu/using-greendao-with-android-studio-ide/.
  It shows how to insert an ID for your entries as well.

Comment: Check this post http://wiki.workassis.com/android-greendao-example/

Answer (score 1):

Greendao is a ORM-framework. If you don't know what this means you should look up this first.

Greendao generally works as follows:

- You create a java-project that generates your sourcecode for your real app. You have to include DaoCore and DaoGenerator in this project.
- You add the generated sourcecode to your android-project and include DaoCore in it. DaoGemerator is not neccessary.

For examples how to generate the code and define your entities the greendao-website is a good place to go.

According to your description you need an entity with id-property and a string-property (affirmation).

In your android-project you then use the DevOpenHelper to get a session and from the session you can get the dao (Data Access Object) for your entity. The dao includes the very basic query to load data by id (`load ()`).

Please notice that the DevOpenHelper is only meant for development process. For your final release you should extend OpenHelper and costumize your actions to be taken on DB-schema update.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code I have in my application.

```
DaoHelper.getInstance().getDaoSession().clear(); 
OperationDao dao = DaoHelper.getInstance().getDaoSession().getOperationDao();
String userId = "some id"
WhereCondition wc1 = new WhereCondition.PropertyCondition(OperationDao.Properties.UserId,
                " = " + userId);
WhereCondition wc2 = new WhereCondition.PropertyCondition(OperationDao.Properties.Priority,
            " > " + 4);
// Uncached is important if your data may have changed recently.
List<Operation> answer = dao.queryBuilder().where(wc1, wc2).listLazyUncached();
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.devteam83.com/en/tutorial-greendao-from-scratch-part-1/) is a decent tutorial on how to learn greendao. Make sure you follow the links to the further parts.

You can use:

```
daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
yourDao = daoSession.getYourDao();

Random() random = new Random();
List<YourObject> objects = yourDao.loadAll();
YourObject yourObject = objects.get(random.nextInt(objects.size());
```